Keep getting TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'user')
I'm new to Nodejs and Express server. I'm trying to create a webapp where user can log in with their Gmail. My front-end uses Reactjs. However, I keep getting this error TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'user')
Here's my code. I use a pretty similar approach for a simple log-in/log-out front-end without Reactjs and it works. However, I don't know what happened with this script which keeps throwing error. Any insight would be greatly appreciate!
passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  process.nextTick(() => {
    return cb(null, { id: user?.id, email: user?.email, googleId: user?.googleId });
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user, cb) => {
  process.nextTick(async () => {
    try {
      const dbUser = await getMemberById(user?.id);
      if (dbUser) {
        dbUser.email = user?.email;
        dbUser.googleId = user?.googleId;
      }
      cb(null, dbUser);
    } catch (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3002/auth/google/callback'
}, async (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
  try {
    console.log('Google profile:', profile);
    let user = await getMemberByName(profile.id);
    if (!user) {
      console.log("User not found, creating new user");
      user = await createMember(profile.emails[0].value, profile.id);
      console.log("New user created:", user);
    }
    user.email = profile.emails?.[0]?.value || null; // Add email to user object if it exists
    user.googleId = profile.id; // Add googleId to user object
    console.log('User object before serialization:', user);
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in authentication process:", error);
    return done(error, null);
  }
}));

I tried research on multiple sources but didn't help even depreciating passportjs to previous version.

Is a new user getting created? What is the output of the statement console.log("New user created:", user);

@WeDoTheBest4You Yes, a new user is created with the output of an object including their email and id. Anw, I figured out what happened, since I tried to use log in method with both Gmail and Slack. For some reasons, the Gmail log-in dependency using Oauth 2 is tandem with the Slack log-in dependency using Oauth 1. After using both Oauth 2, the bug is fixed.
